# Gitlab CI: automatically merge main into the feature branch on each push

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I would like to have my developers frequently integrate changes in the mainline into their feature breaches on each push of feature branch to the remote.

1. Dev makes change in their feature branch
2. Daily, dev stages, commits and pushes to remote
3. Remote push triggers CI pipe which runs runs unit tests on that feature branch
4. If tests pass, trigger automatic merging of the mainline into the feature branch to integrate <<< I WANT TO ENABLE THIS
5. Run tests again in CI to confirm merge did not break anything
6. Devs pull feature branch to continue work
7. Eventually once ready, feature will be reviewed and merged into the mainline

In above flow, step 4 is what I'm looking for. I want to enforce early and frequent integration of mainline changes into currently developed feature breaches.

How can I achieve this?

I have an idea but just wonder if this is the right way or if there is a better way.

I'm thinking to add an additional job in pipe named “integrate” which would run git merge main on that feature branch to integrate the mainline into it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there any way to auto merge branches in gitlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516773/is-there-any-way-to-auto-merge-branches-in-gitlab)

Comment: @ndclt Thanks, I will take a look, it seem to be close to it